# Error with display tag

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I have a List of objects which has the following attributes

public class ViewTestCasesBean {

```
private String testcaseName;
private String subject;
private String description;
private List<TestCaseDetailsBean> testList = new ArrayList<TestCaseDetailsBean>();

// GETTERS AND SETTERS SECTION.......///////

public String getTestcaseName() {
    return testcaseName;
}

public void setTestcaseName(String testcaseName) {
    this.testcaseName = testcaseName;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public List<TestCaseDetailsBean> getTestList() {
    return testList;
}

public void setTestList(List<TestCaseDetailsBean> testList) {
    this.testList = testList;
}
```

}

Now my action code is...

```
   public String execute() {


    detailsList = viewTestCasesTransaction.fetchTestCases();
    session.put("testcaseList", detailsList);

    if (detailsList.size() > 0) {

        return SUCCESS;
    }
    return ERROR;
}
```

Here detailsList is the List of the above object to be displayed in the display tag.

I tried with the following

```
 <jsp:root version="1.2" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
xmlns:c="urn:jsptld:http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
<%@page import="org.apache.jasper.tagplugins.jstl.core.Import"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.harmony.cloud.bean.TestCaseDetailsBean"%>
<%@ page import="com.harmony.cloud.action.ViewTestCasesAction"%>

<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>

<html>
   <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

 <title>Test Cases List</title>


  </head>
   <body>
<%session.getAttribute("testcaseList"); %>
<display:table name="detailsList" id="parent">
    <display:column property="testcaseName" />
    <display:column property="subject" />
    <display:column property="description" title="Comments" />

    <c:set var="nestedName"
        value="detailsList[${parent_rowNum -1}].testcaseList}" />
 <display:table  name="${nestedName}" id="child${parent_rowNum}" >
    <display:column title="Steps">
</display:table>
</display:column>

  <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="top" />

        </display:table>

  </body>
</html>
```

But got the following error.........

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /testCasesView.jsp (line: 3, column: 3) The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup. 
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:89)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.parse(JspDocumentParser.java:207)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:226)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:119)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:193)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:164)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:374)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:278)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:432)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
      org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
      org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Whats wrong with the coding?

Comment: as per exception, this expression looks incorrect `detailsList.item[${parent_rowNum -1}].subList`. so change this expression to `${detailsList.item[parent_rowNum - 1].subList}` and try. post your response back!

Comment: @jeevatkm got the same error

Comment: Can you update your post with complete code snippets of java class and testCasesView.jsp?

Comment: @jeevatkm I have updated the code please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Take care of following elements:**

1) `<jsp:root ...>` does not have closing tag

2) Value expression has additional of curly brace and class attribute `testcaseList` not present `<c:set var="nestedName" value="detailsList[${parent_rowNum -1}].testcaseList}" />`, so change it to `<c:set var="nestedName" value="detailsList[${parent_rowNum -1}].testList" />`

3) display:column tag of nested table missing `property` attribute `<display:column title="Steps">`

4) Place doctype in the first line of file `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

5) This one is just a question, you're retrieving session attribute but not assigning it. did this on purpose?

Example from displaytag-examples-1.2.war -> [example-nestedtables.jsp](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/displaytag/displaytag-examples/1.2/displaytag-examples-1.2.war!/example-nestedtables.jsp?format=ok)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse IDE, when you create the JSP create a JSP with html markup or xhtml markup following the wizard. You do not want to create a JSP with JSP 2.0 specific tags, xhtml markup. 
Project -> new -> JSP File -> check Use JSP Template -> New JSP File with xhtml/html markup.